# valueChangeListener Not fired when rendered/disabled attribute is added

Tags: jsp, jsf

I have the following peace of code:

```
        <h:selectOneMenu id="countrycode"
                styleClass="Width300"
                value="#{customer.countrycode}"
                valueChangeListener="#{customer.countrycodechange}"
                onchange="submit()"
                immediate="true"
                rendered="#{customer.validcountry}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="None"
                    itemLabel="-------Select a Country------" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="AU" itemLabel="Australia" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="NZ" itemLabel="New Zealand" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

The ValueChangeListener works only if i leave out the rendered attribute, with rendered attribute the `countrycodechange` never gets fired! Is there a way around this?

Same is true for adding `disabled` attribute , which stops `valueChangeListener` from firing. My `valueChangeListener` backbean has:

```
    public void countrycodechange (ValueChangeEvent vce) {

        PhaseId phaseId = vce.getPhaseId();
        if (phaseId.equals(PhaseId.ANY_PHASE))
        {
            vce.setPhaseId(PhaseId.UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES);
            vce.queue();
        }
        else if (phaseId.equals(PhaseId.UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES))
        {
            ...
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input components will only be processed when their `rendered` and `disabled` attributes evaluate respectively to `true` and `false` **during** the form submit. So, you need to make sure that `#{customer.validcountry}` evaluates the same during the form submit as it did during displaying the form. Apparently in your case the bean is request scoped or the `isValidcountry()` depends on a request scoped parameter which isn't properly preserved during the form submit. You need to make sure that you preserve the same condition during the form submit.

In JSF 2.0 that would be a matter of putting the bean in the view scope instead of the request scope. However, seeing your `valueChangeListener` hack, I think that you're still using JSF 1.x which does not have the view scope yet. The right solution is hard to propose without seeing the rest of the code. It does at least not make sense to me to have a rendered attribute on "is a valid country?" while the input component *itself* should select a valid country.