# valueChangeListener isn't always triggered depending on the rendered attribute

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, valuechangelistener

I'm having trouble to understand why valueChangeListener isn't triggered.
I came accross this topic [valueChangeListener Not fired when rendered/disabled attribute is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252304/valuechangelistener-not-fired-when-rendered-disabled-attribute-is-added) 
but it didn't help so much.

When my xhtml is this :

```
<h:inputText value="#{cm.reference}" 
                    rendered="#{cm.endDate eq null}"
                    valueChangeListener="#{userDataBean.ContactMethodChanged}" />
```

it's working (*I mean the valueChangeListener is triggered*)

But when I try this :

```
<h:inputText value="#{cm.reference}" 
                    rendered="#{cm.contactMethodId eq param.contactMethodID}"
                    valueChangeListener="#{userDataBean.ContactMethodChanged}" />
```

it doesn't.

Unfortunately I need to have the second option working.

More info :
I'm inside a h:dataTable where I iterate on a list of ContactMethod (cm)
 
UserDataBean is applicationScoped
Apache Tomcat 7.0
JSF 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2.0)

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is not processed during the form submit, then that can only mean that the `rendered` attribute didn't evaluate `true` during processing the form submit, which in turn can only mean that the `#{cm.contactMethodId}` has incompatibly changed (e.g. because it's a request scoped bean property instead of a view scoped bean property) and/or that `#{param.contactMethodID}` isn't present during the form submit.

Provided that the bean is in the right scope for the job (otherwise the original `rendered` approach would likely not have worked either), then retaining the request parameter as follows in the command button/link responsible for submitting the form should do it:

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:param name="contactMethodID" value="#{param.contactMethodID}" />
</h:commandButton>
```